# Why can't I submit web form to gmail?

Tags: github

I used a simple html5up template for this webform with no PHP backend. It is a github.io page.

CODE: https://github.com/tcffo-volunteers/tcffo-volunteers.github.io

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `action` parameter should be something like `https://formspree.io/your@email.com`, it is `https://https://www.formspree.io/tcffo.volunteers@gmail.com` in your code.

Can you try `https://formspree.io/tcffo.volunteers@gmail.com` and see if this fixes it? And check your spam folder in Gmail.

Comment: I made those adjustments but still nothing in the spam folder

Comment: @dnap Actually, I think the problem is here... https://github.com/tcffo-volunteers/tcffo-volunteers.github.io/blob/master/assets/js/main.js#L141 your `main.js` is blocking the submit button.